# Unable to access Kibana dashboard service in kubernetes cluser on Ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I am trying to access the Kibana dashboard while trying to set up fluentd-elasticsearch on premises. This is the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch) which I followed. I checked the logs of Kibana's pod. It shows the following error:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-19T21:45:42Z","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1,"message":"You should set server.basePath along with server.rewriteBasePath. Starting in 7.0, Kibana will expect that all requests start with server.basePath rather than expecting you to rewrite the requests in your reverse proxy. Set server.rewriteBasePath to false to preserve the current behavior and silence this warning."}
root@mTrainer3:/logging# kubectl logs kibana-logging-66d577d965-mbbg5 -n kube-system
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-19T21:45:42Z","tags":["warning","config","deprecation"],"pid":1,"message":"You should set server.basePath along with server.rewriteBasePath. Starting in 7.0, Kibana will expect that all requests start with server.basePath rather than expecting you to rewrite the requests in your reverse proxy. Set server.rewriteBasePath to false to preserve the current behavior and silence this warning."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-19T21:46:08Z","tags":["status","plugin:kibana@6.4.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
```

Could anybody suggest how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: How are you trying to get to Kibana? All I see in the logs is warnings.

Comment: Hi Rico, he stated a link to the github repo of k8s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*After a discussion it was more clear what seems to be wrong.*

You are using a local cluster with no load balancer. You have to set either an ingress or use NodePort as the service type. I am going to describe the solution with NodePort. Two steps to take:

1. Modify the `kibana-deployment.yaml` and remove the following under `env`:

```
- name: SERVER_BASEPATH
  value: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging/proxy
```

so that you `kibana-deployment.yaml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
  matchLabels:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kibana-logging
      annotations:
        seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: 'docker/default'
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana-logging
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.3.2
        resources:
          # need more cpu upon initialization, therefore burstable class
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        env:
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
            value: http://elasticsearch-logging:9200
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
          name: ui
          protocol: TCP
```

2. Modify `kibana-service.yaml` to set the service type to NodePort:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    kubernetes.io/name: "Kibana"
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: ui
    nodePort: 30601
  selector:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
```

Then execute

```
kubectl apply -f kibana-deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f kibana-service.yaml
```

Kibana should be accessible at `http://<clusterip>:30601`

**Background**

You will directly access `http://clusterip:30601` without the given base path. So this must be removed, so that kibana is using `/` as base path. Otherwise it will try to append the base path /api/v1/[...] to your url. You can try it if you want to test it.

[This comment from an elastic search guy mentions](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/plugin-installation-failure/63422/4), that you have to remove the base_path completely if you want to use `/`.

Modifying the service to NodePort is neccessary as K8s does not publish ports by default. I just answered a similar issue on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413160/connect-connection-refused-when-connecting-prometheus-to-kubernetes/52414776#52414776).

**Original answer (wrong)**

In the repo you were linking I can see that the kibana-deployment.yaml has to environment variables to set:

```
env:
  - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
    value: http://elasticsearch-logging:9200
  - name: SERVER_BASEPATH
    value: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging/proxy
```

Did you set them accordingly?

Let's assume you have an ingress, loadbalancer or NodePort directly to the kibana instance so that you want to reach it directly with http://yourserver:9200/. Then the `SERVER_BASEPATH` is `/`

Comment: Thank you christoph.  i ran with default configurations which they provided in the link. I didn't make any changes.Now which url should i use to hit the kibana service to view the dashboard?

Comment: Hi @GayathriBalipalli Do you work on a local machine? Do you use something like minikube? Or a service like google platform?

Comment: Hi @christoph.  i am working on local ubuntu machine(kubernets cluster).

Comment: How did you deploy kibana? `kubectl apply -f kibana-deployment.yaml` and `kibana-service.yaml`?

Comment: yes  christoph. I deployed like `kubectl create -f  kibana-deployment.yaml` and `kibana-service.yaml`

Comment: Okay, one more question before I try to help: How did you try to access kibana then, with the default files? Which "link" did you use, so that you saw the mentioned log-lines? Or did you only check the pod's log output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180474/discussion-between-gayathribalipalli-and-christoph).

Comment: Great, it's working!   May i know in which cases we will use that removed env variable in our deployment?

Comment: You need the basepath if you are behind a proxy, where you do not use the "normal" base path `/`. For example if you set up a Apache proxy under `http://host/my/kibana/instance`, the base_patch would be `/my/kibana/instance`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also specify Kibana to rewrite server basepath by specifying an environment variable.

Modify `kibana-deployment.yaml` to add the following.

```
- name: SERVER_REWRITEBASEPATH
  value: "true"
```

Now apply:
`kubectl apply -f kibana-deployment.yaml`

Tested this on `microk8s` and works well with `kubectl proxy`

http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging/proxy/app/kibana